# Not able to parse local xml file with javascript

Tags: javascript, xml, xmlhttprequest, xml-parsing

When i try to parse local xml file using simple javascript, the code after xhr.open is not getting executed.

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function createXMLHttpRequestObject()
{
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
      xhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else {
      xhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }

    return xhttp;
}

function makeRequest()
{
    var xhr = createXMLHttpRequestObject();

    try {
    xhr.open("GET", 'books.xml', false);
    xhr.send(null);
    //xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
     //if(this.readyState == 4) {
      xmlDoc=xhr.responseXML;
     alert(xmlDoc);
     //}
   }
   } catch( err ) {
        alert("ERROR: " + err.description);
    }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div onclick="makeRequest();">test<br></div>
    <div id="out">Output Here</div>
</body>
</html>
```

the books.xml file is as below,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<!-- Edited by XMLSpy® -->

<bookstore>

    <book category="COOKING">
      <title lang="en">Everyday Italian</title>
      <author>Giada De Laurentiis</author>
      <year>2005</year>
      <price>30.00</price>
    </book>

    <book category="CHILDREN">
      <title lang="en">Harry Potter</title>
      <author>J K. Rowling</author>
      <year>2005</year>
      <price>29.99</price>
    </book>

    <book category="WEB">
      <title lang="en">XQuery Kick Start</title>
      <author>James McGovern</author>
      <author>Per Bothner</author>
      <author>Kurt Cagle</author>
      <author>James Linn</author>
      <author>Vaidyanathan Nagarajan</author>
      <year>2003</year>
      <price>49.99</price>
    </book>

    <book category="WEB">
      <title lang="en">Learning XML</title>
      <author>Erik T. Ray</author>
      <year>2003</year>
      <price>39.95</price>
    </book>

</bookstore>
```

When searched on internet i found that "For security reasons, modern browsers do not allow access across domains." 
http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_parser.asp

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of setting web server on localhost....simply download [aptana studi](http://www.aptana.com/studio/download)o software and import your project in it...and run your html file, aptana directly open browser and automatically create web server with name  **http://127.0.0.1:8000/yourprojectName**

After that you will not receive any error.

Answer (score 0):

Local files are best considered a no-go area. Security restrictions are pretty high. Run a web server on localhost instead and use that to access your page.

Answer (score 0):

you may try to use a local web server to resolve the problem quickly.